# SignalR .NET Client connecting to wss URL - if not possible, alternative solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I need a [ClientWebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=net-6.0) wrapper in order to connect and collect data from [wss://stream.binance.com:9443](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#general-wss-information). The received data should be broadcasted to the UI (realtime UI) through a web socket server.

The broadcast part can be achieved using SignalR .NET Server. It is documented on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr#install-the-stockticker-sample).

The client web socket part is what I can't imagine. I found a [SignalR .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that I can use to connect to *wss://stream.binance.com:9443*, however I don't think it is possible, because SignalR probably has its own transport protocol. Is it correct?

If the Signal .NET Client doesn't work in my case, could you please direct me to alternative solutions? I was looking at the following

1. https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client
2. https://github.com/skunklab/piraeus/tree/96fcbc854d0c8d2c2cd62e457f06ef638859b6eb/src/SkunkLab.Channels/WebSocket
3. https://gist.github.com/xamlmonkey/4737291

It's worth stating that the ClientWebSocket subscriptions to Binance will be created for multiple API keys (unknown amount of users - based on DB user records).

Comment: In the end you're asking for a .net web socket client lib AND you're asking "is there a better lib to do server / client communication than Signal/R". Both questions do not work very well for SO.

Comment: You have web sockets support in the framework or you can add a lib with some more features.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen, removed that part. Like I said, there is no problem with the broadcasting to the UI. The problem is that I need a ClientWebSocket wrapper to subscribe to Binance's web socket (wss URL)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen, I could use the socket from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0, but I would still need a wrapper around it.

Comment: No, you don't need a wrapper. You can use the way described in this tutorial or you can use a lib like (1) or build your own lightweight wrapper. Choose what you like?

Comment: I'm the author of the `websocket-client` wrapper, I have also prepared a client for Binance https://github.com/Marfusios/binance-client-websocket that you can use